# Tor hidden service on Raspberry Pi

Tags: onion-services, raspberry-pi

I want to set up a Tor hidden service on a Raspberry Pi. What is a good way to do that? Maybe start with Occidentalis v0.2 by Adafruit?

Is there a special tutorial for the Raspberry PI?

Comment: It's Tor not TOR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would depend on what distro you are using. I have Tor running pretty well on ARCH on my PI, there are good instructions [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/tor).

I did have an issue with "Problem with user value" but that is also detailed on the how to

Other than that it seems just the same as any other Linux OS, so you can follow the [usual instructions](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-hidden-service.html.en)